# In Stripe while doing a checkout flow is it possible to collect a one time amount now and start the subscription at a future date?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to do an integration with Stripe where I want to allow checkout subscription for multiple line items. Where I want to collect a one time charge and then the monthly subscription should start at a future date. (pls note that during checkout I dont have the customer ID information as it is a guest experience)

I tried:

1. creating a subscription with 0$ and later tried updating through webhook to some amount with the help of : `stripe.subscriptionSchedules.update`
   I tried to provide a start date using `start_date` field.
   This gives a following error:

```
StripeInvalidRequestError: There is a gap between phase 0 `(1693390410, 1696068810)` and phase 1 `(1703956194, 1725037794)`.
```

2. I also tried to update the price using webhook and applied a pause to the subscription at the same time. But I am not sure how to test it out.

```
//update the schedule with the new monthly price
            schedule = await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.update(
                schedule.id,
                {
                    end_behavior: "cancel",
                    phases: [
                        ...phases,
                        {
                            items: [
                                {
                                    price: 'abc',
                                    quantity: 1,
                                },
                                {
                                    price: 'xyz',
                                    quantity: 1,
                                }
                            ],
                            // trial_end: 1703956194,
                            start_date: 1703956194,
                            iterations: 8
                        }
                    ],
                }
            )

            // pause the subscription to resume at a later date
            const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(
                checkoutSession.subscription,
                {
                  pause_collection: {
                    behavior: 'void',
                    resumes_at: 1703956194
                  },
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is this:
-Have a recurring Price (`price_recurring`)
-Have a one-time Price (`price_once`)
Worth mentioning that you don't actually need to have these Prices set on your account, you can generate them on the `sessions.create()` using `price_data`:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=node#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data

Then create your Session in `subscription` mode with both `price_recurring` and `price_once` in `line_items`.
The one-time Price will only apply to the first Invoice of the Subscription, while the Subscription will bill for the recurring Price every cycle.

Now, this isn't exactly what you want, since you don't want the recurring Price to be charged on the first Invoice if I understand well.
To fix that, you can either:
-Add a once-duration Coupon for 100% discount that only applies to your recurring Product on the Session.
-Add a trial using `subscription_data.trial_end`

However, if what you want is for the Session *to only show the one item, and update to the other item later*, then you can't do this in a single Session call (except maybe with a once-duration Coupon) - you would have to create a Session then update your Subscription when it's created.